# How to create stream of integers dynamically based on certain condition while iterating on existing stream in java 8

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have stream of sequential long values like {1,2,.....n} where n is max of long value is possible.
from this stream i need to take each element of stream/iterate the stream and create another group of stream until certain condtion is met.

Ex

```
n= 10 -> {1,2,,,,10} This is my original stream
While iterate i need to create another set of stream to check a condition if the sum of sequnce is particular number ex 15 and identify how many possible sequence of sum of 15 is possible.
1
1+2
1+2+3
1+2+3+4+5 == 15 break counter =1

2
2+3
2+3+4+5
2+3+4+5+6 > 15 break
```

In java 7 we can do this with 2 loops. how to achieve this in Java 8 with stream

Answer (score 1):

If performance isn't a concern...

```
int n = 10;
int expectedSum = 15;
long count = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, n).mapToLong(i -> 
    IntStream.rangeClosed(i + 1, n).mapToObj(j -> 
        IntStream.rangeClosed(i, j)
    ).filter(intStream -> intStream.sum() == expectedSum)
    .count()
).sum();
```

Comment: does this perform better than traditional for loop or how to confirm from performance perspective

Comment: @springbootlearner This performs poorly because it generates all sequences before filtering them to find those that have the expected sum. Traditional for loops may or may not perform better depending on the algorithm. You can time how long it takes yourself and compare that to when for loops are used.